# Underscores and Binary Literals in java 7.!!!??

Tags: java, java-7

What will be the result?

```
int i=1_00_00;  
int b=0b1_00;
```

Will it display underscores?

```
if(i.equals(10000)){   
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Will it converts binary to decimal?

```
if(b.equals(8)){  
    System.out.println(b);
}
```

Comment: @LukasEder It would have to compile first. ;)

Answer (score 3):

The `_` is just there to improve readability.  You can use `.equals` or any method with primitives, just print out the values, you don't need to check them first.

> will it display underscores?

There is not way to store underscores in a primitive (apart from char ch = '_')

> will it converts binary to decimal?

All numbers are stored in binary, so this would be nothing new. ;)